# FATAL ERROR deploying CRA app to Google Cloud

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I tried to deploy a Create React App app to Google Cloud but got the following error:

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

Comment: [Self-answered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) are accepted here, but they must be posted as a question and answer, and both must meet the same standards as any other Q&A (e.g. don't post images of code).

Comment: Whatever. Im sure people stuck on this issue will be happy if my post can help.

Answer (score -1):

1. `npm run build`
2. create a `app.yaml` file in the root folder that contains a "handlers" attribute listing all the paths to the files you want to deploy. See example of YAML file in the image below.

   [image: app.yaml]